# How could i manipulate a list comprehension?

Tags: haskell, list-comprehension

First time posting, sorry if I am doing something wrong or am unclear about my question

I'm pretty new to Haskell and I am having a hard time figuring out how could I manipulate a list comprehension to show me what I want. I have two functions that give me lists of tuples(they are basically matrices, one of which is full, the other is random)

I want to create a new list (matrix) with the list comprehension which would return whether `list2` tuple was the same as `list1` tuple.

For example:

```
list1 = [(0,0),(0,1),(0,2),(1,0),(1,1),(1,2),(2,0),(2,1),(2,2)]
list2 = [(1,0),(1,1)]
result = [False, False, False, True, True, False, False, False, False]
```

But the list comprehension I've written gives me a cartesian product

```
[False,False,False,True,False,False,False,False,False,False,False,False,False,True,False,False,False,False]
```

The list comprehension continues to compare the tuple from List2 even after it has found the same one in List1.

This is how I've written my list comprehension :

```
[ (x==y) | x <- (list2), y <- (list1)]
```

I'm pretty sure there must be some sort of predicate that can be written in the list comprehension to get what I want, but I've no clue how to realise that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is e membership check, so you can implement this as:

```
[ x `elem` list2 | x <- list1 ]
```

But simpler is probably to work with [**`map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:map):

```
map (`elem` list2) list1
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this works perfectly :), but could you please explain to me what do `elem` and map do exactly?

Comment: @SpaceDuckas: ``x `elem` y`` checks if `x` is an element of the "collection" `y`. `map` will map every element `x` of `list2` in this case ``x `elem` list2``.

Comment: A little bit of topic, but how would I go about trying to turn bools into ints in this situation? fromEnum doesn't seem to be working on bools that are in a list

Comment: @SpaceDuckas: you can do another `map fromEnum`, so ``map fromEnum (map (`elem` list2) list1)``